# kpss test always gives a very low P value

Tags: r, time-series, kpss-test

I have tried to use `kpss.test()` function in `R`, but it's output confused me a lot. So I tried the below code:

```
t = 1:100
y = 10*t
set.seed(1)
z = rnorm(100, 0, 100)
time <- z + y
plot(time)
kpss.test(time, null = "Trend")
```

the $y$ is clearly a function of time, and $z$ is stationary series, but the `kpss.test` output shows that `P-value = 0.09702`, as the $H_0$ states that data is trend stationary, I believe the data is a perfect trend stationary data already, why the P-value is still so low. Any kind advice or answer would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try doing the simulation 1000 times or so and see how many times you reject at a given alpha, say 0.1. If you get 100 rejections out of those 1000 simulations, the test is performing exactly as it should be.

Comment: @DaveDa， thanks for your reply, I dont understand what you meant, why need to do simulation? here i am asking for the clarification for kpss.test, not the meaning of P-value, excuse me if I didn't get your point

Comment: You’re finding that the p-value falls below the threshold for statistical significance that you’re using, seemingly 0.1, even though the null hypothesis is true. That’s supposed to happen 10% of the time (for $\alpha=0.1$). I am saying to see how the test performs over many samples. Maybe this particular simulation had the bad luck of giving a false positive.

Comment: @DaveDa, understand that you are saying the P-value = 0.1 means there is still 10% chance for H0 to be true. but my confusion is the time series that I created is an perfect trend stationary, why the chance is still 10%(so low!!!!), this 10% is a stable output as I have set the seed as 1. so no matter how many times I tried to run adf.test, it still give me P-Value = 0.1. I guess either I have done some mistakes or I have misused the adf.test.

Comment: You don’t set the seed to 1 each time you do the loop. Set the seed at 1 at the top of your script. Then do the loop. The loop will vary your z term each time. The reason to set the seed at the beginning is so that I can reproduce your results exactly on my own computer, not to get the same result from each iteration of the loop. (That will happen if you set the seed in the loop, so avoid doing that.)

Comment: @Dave, ok, i tried to re-run the code 10 times, the P-value is actually the same. because the data is generated with same distribution, and I guess maybe kpss.test P-value's maximum is 0.1, as I increased the pattern by setting y = 10000*sin(0.1*t), in the end, kpss still gives P-value = 0.1

Comment: Hi: According to the link below, there is  no function argument called null and there should be three outputs ? It's possible that there are two kpss.test functions in R in which case, try the one from the aTSA package  and see what it gives.  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/aTSA/versions/3.1.2/topics/kpss.test

Comment: It turns out there are two functions so the best thing to do is investigate whether they give consistent results. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tseries/versions/0.10-47/topics/kpss.test

Comment: Why do you have ADF test in the title of your question? The body does not seem to justify that.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, I actually meant both adf and kpss, but forgot to put the code for adf, so just deleted, seems adf test must set the k=0 to test the original series, or it will set automatically the default lags for it, this is probably the cause for Low P-value